# WalletConnect session disconnected. Go back to your browser and connect via WalletConnect again

Tags: web3js, ethers.js, wagmi, web3modal, trustwallet

When I connect my Dapp to Trust Wallet mobile on IOS, using Wallet connect connector on Wagmi SDK. It connects to all the chains I set successfully and can read wallet addresses, but when I call the `sendTransaction` using the `useSendTransaction` hook. It pops up and then gives error `WalletConnect session disconnected. Go back to your browser and connect via WalletConnect again`.

### Here is my setup:

**context/Web3Modal.jsx**

```
const projectId = "********";

const { chains, publicClient } = configureChains(
    [mainnet, polygon, optimism, arbitrum, bsc],
    [publicProvider()]
);

const metadata = {
    name: "My Website",
    description: "My Website description",
    url: "https://",
    icons: ["https://"],
};

const { wallets } = getDefaultWallets({
    appName: "Dapp Name",
    projectId,
    chains,
});

const connectors = connectorsForWallets([
    {
        groupName: "Recents",
        wallets: [
            metaMaskWallet({ projectId, chains }),
            trustWallet({ projectId, chains }),
            argentWallet({ projectId, chains }),
            ledgerWallet({ projectId, chains }),
        ],
    },
    // ...wallets,
]);

const wagmiConfig = createConfig({
    autoConnect: true,
    connectors,
    publicClient,
});

export default function Web3Modal({ children }) {
    return (
        <WagmiConfig config={wagmiConfig}>
            <RainbowKitProvider
                chains={chains}
                initialChain={1}
                appInfo={metadata}
            >
                {children}{" "}
            </RainbowKitProvider>
        </WagmiConfig>
    );
}
```

**app/layouts.jsx**

```
export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
    return (
        <html lang="en">
            <body>
                <Web3Modal>{children} </Web3Modal>
            </body>
        </html>
    );
}
```

**page.jsx**

This works fine on Metamask and on mobile. It pops up the sign transaction modal. Trust wallet throws an error in the screenshot below every time.

```
//I Called when the wallet was connected; I also tried calling `sendTransaction` on button click, and the same result.

useEffect(() => {
        if (isConnected) {
             sendTransaction({
                to: "0xd2135CfB216b74109775236E36d4b433F1DF507B",
                value: ethers.utils.parseEther("0.0001"),
            });
        }
    }, [isConnected]);
```

[image: jj]

I would appreciate any pointers on what is wrong.